# Problem: resize of elements with "onclick" function at certain screen width

Tags: javascript, html, mpmediaquery

I would need some help regarding media queries applied to javascript. Is it possible to resize an object starting from the javascript code with a screen width other than the "default" one?

Example: I have a button, and when I click on it, it opens me a div with a height of 600px. the screen here is 1600px wide. can I make sure that when the screen is for example at 1000px wide, the div that is shown has a height of 800px? And if it is possible, can this happen several times, that is, that the condition does not disappear once this div is closed and then repoened?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is probably with css media queries

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   div {
      height: 800px;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't do what you say because here I put the height of the div when it is closed and only in the javascript file I go to define the height of the open div.

Comment: Html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 #div1{height:600px;}
</style>
<body>
 <div id="div1" onclick="functionA()">
  <p></p>
  <img src="">
  ...
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Javascript code:

var open = false;
function functionA(){
 if(!open){
  document.getElementById("div1").style.height="800px";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("div1").style.height="600px";
 }
}